# How to make a command line program in C

Tags: c

I want to create a command line program in C that is supposed to allow users to enter my custom command, choose an option, and perform functions on a user file. The program will perform different functions depending on which option is chosen. The program should also be able to identify if the files are present or not on the computer.

For example, if my custom command is `encodethis` , the user will enter `encodethis -e <filename>` to encode the file.

This is what I've tried so far in order to check if the user entered the right argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* main function to copy strings*/

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {

    if (argc == 3) {
        if (strcmp (argv[0], "myencode") == 0) {
            if (strcmp (argv[1], "-e") ==0) {
                 /* Check user input against files in computer*/
```

The problem for me now is to somehow check the user inputted file name against the files in his computer to see if it exists or not. I do not know how to check the 3rd value in the `argv[]` array since it is entered by the user and is undefined at first. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: why do you think it is undefined? if `argc` is 3 then `argv[2]` should contain something

Comment: Why are you checking `argv[0]` at all? Do you *really* want your program to abort or fail if it's renamed, or just called in such a manner that `argv[0]` is unset, or if a qualified path such as `/path/to/myencode` rather than the `myencode` basename is present in that field?

Comment: And if the thing you're stuck on is checking if the file exists, your question should be *only* about that, with everything else (ie. the command-line argument list bits) factored out.

Comment: @ChrisTurner What I meant was I needed to find what argv[2] is, and it being undefined means that it doesn't have a set value, and is inputted by the user

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm afraid I do not understand what your first comment means. If I don't check the first element of the argv[0] array, how do I know if the user is entering myencode as the first word and not something else?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Never mind. I figured out what your comment meant. So does that mean I should start the check from argv[1] instead?

Comment: Yes, you should validate only `argv[1]` and later, unless you have an unusual special case (such as a program that runs in different modes based on its name -- `gzip`/`gunzip`, for instance)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see. Thanks for the advice. My program does not have a special case so I guess I should validate argv[1] and later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* main function to copy strings*/

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {

    if (argc == 3) {
        if (strcmp (argv[0], "myencode") == 0) {
            if (strcmp (argv[1], "-e") ==0) {
                 /* Check user input against files in computer*/
                FILE *fp;
                fp = fopen(argv[2],"r+");
                if (fp!=NULL){
                    /* your stuff goes here, don't forget to close
                       the file with fclose(fp) 
                    */
                }else{
                printf("Error: could not open file\n");
            }
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Source: [C File I/O](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does that FILE *fp part mean that the user can input any file name they want, and it will check their computer to see if any of that file exists?

Comment: the `fopen()` function returns a pointer to FILE if the file is opened, `NULL` otherwise. The opening can fail if the file is not found or if there are not enough permissions or whatever other reason. "File not found" is just one of the possibilities due to  `fopen()` could return `NULL`.

Comment: I see, so `fp = fopen(argv[2],"r+");` means that the program will check the 3rd element in the argv[] array and try to open that file name?

Comment: the program will try to open the file specified in the `argv[2]` string in `read/write` mode, yeah. It's all in the link I put after the code ;)